# Tool that can scan and organize all Cucumber feature files

Tags: cucumber, bdd

Living documentation plays a crucial role in BDD. However, the current organization of Cucumber feature files does not facilitate easy navigation and extraction of simple information from BDD scenarios, especially for non-technical individuals.

I'm in search of a tool that can scan and organize all feature files, possesses a web interface, and enables users to effortlessly browse through feature files. Additionally, the tool should allow for searching specific BDD scenarios and categorizing files based on different criteria such as tags, rules, and features.

Do you know if such a tool is available? It's important to note that I'm not seeking a cucumber reporting tool. If such a tool doesn't exist, do you have any suggestions on how to achieve a similar outcome that fulfills my requirements to the greatest extent possible?